# Get elements between 2 elements that have specific properties

Tags: html, xpath

Here's something similar to the HTML I'm working with:

```
<body>

  <tr class="heading">
    <td colspan="2"> Heading 1 </td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>L 1</td>
    <td>R 1</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>L 2</td>
    <td>R 2</td>
  </tr>

  <tr class="heading">
    <td colspan="2"> Heading 2</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>L 3</td>
    <td>R 3</td>
  </tr>

</body>
```

I want to get all `td[1]`s from the `tr`s after "Heading 1" but not anything after "Heading 2" (or including "Heading 2").

Ideally I need to be able to do this with only "Heading 1" as the input - I want all elements under the heading I supply, but ignoring anything under a new heading.

Is this possible in XPath?

Answer (score 1):

I took the code from your deleted answer and made it work...and ugly:

```
(//tr[preceding-sibling::tr[@class='heading' and td=' Heading 1 '] and following-sibling::tr[@class='heading']]/td[1] ) | (//tr[preceding-sibling::tr[@class='heading' and td=' Heading 1 '] and following-sibling::tr[@class='heading']]/td[2] )
```

If you are using a programming language, it might be better to do it in code.

Comment: This is almost correct, but it selects all `td` elements, not just the one in the first position, relative to its parent.

Answer (score 1):

I do not agree with any of the answers so far. An XPath expression that does exactly what you are asking is

```
//tr[@class = 'heading' and normalize-space(td) = 'Heading 1']/following::td[following::tr[@class = 'heading' and normalize-space(td) = 'Heading 2']]
```

which translates to

```
//tr                                     select all `tr` elements anywhere in the document
[@class = 'heading'                      but only if they have a `class` attribute whose
                                         value is equal to "heading"                
and normalize-space(td) = 'Heading 1']   and only if they contain a `td` element which has
                                         a string value of "Heading 1".
/following::td                           select all `td` elements that follow them
[following::tr                           but only if they are followed by a `tr` element
[@class = 'heading'                      which again has a `class` attribute with "heading"
                                         as its value
and normalize-space(td) = 'Heading 2']]  and only if this `tr` element has a `td` child
                                         element with "Heading 2" as its string value
```

and which will return the following (individual results separated by `------`):

```
<td>L 1</td>
-----------------------
<td>R 1</td>
-----------------------
<td>L 2</td>
-----------------------
<td>R 2</td>
```

The `normalize-space()` function is there to strip strings of trailing whitespace.

---

**EDIT**: If you intended to only select the *first* of several `td` elements:

```
//tr[@class = 'heading' and normalize-space(td) = 'Heading 1']/following::tr/td[position() = 1 and following::tr[@class = 'heading' and normalize-space(td) = 'Heading 2']]
```

and the result will be

```
<td>L 1</td>
-----------------------
<td>L 2</td>
```

To be even more complete, to account for a situation like the following:

```
<body>

  <tr class="heading">
    <td colspan="2"> Heading 1 </td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>L 1</td>
    <td>R 1</td>
<td>third</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>L 2</td>
    <td>R 2</td>
  </tr>

  <tr class="heading">
    <td colspan="2"> Heading other</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>L 3</td>
    <td>R 3</td>
  </tr>

<tr class="heading">
    <td colspan="2"> Heading 2</td>
  </tr>

</body>
```

where there are unrelated headings in between "Heading 1" and "Heading 2", whose child `td` element should not appear in the result, use

```
//tr[@class = 'heading' and normalize-space(td) = 'Heading 1']/following::tr[not(@class)]/td[position() = 1 and following::tr[@class = 'heading' and normalize-space(td) = 'Heading 2']]
```

---

**EDIT**:

> At the moment, your xpath finds the elements between 2 headers, but in the case of the last group on the page the page, there isn't going to a 2nd header to reference.

Until now, you did not explain that this is the case in your actual data. Use

```
//tr[@class = 'heading' and normalize-space(td) = 'Heading 1']/following::tr[not(@class)]/td[position() = 1 and not(preceding::tr[@class = 'heading' and normalize-space(td) = 'Heading 2'])]
```

---

**EDIT 2**:

> I do, but I also added the note "Ideally I need to be able to do this with only "Heading 1" as the input - I want all elements under the heading I supply, but ignoring anything under a new heading."

```
//tr[@class = 'heading' and normalize-space(td) = 'Heading 1']/following::tr[not(@class)]/td[position() = 1 and not(preceding::tr[@class = 'heading' and normalize-space(td) != 'Heading 1'])]
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer, as far as I can tell this won't work for something which doesn't have a heading under it, correct? It also doesn't allow me to just specify "Heading 1" and get all the rows it relates to! I ended up just doing it in a programming language instead.

Comment: @Joe _"this won't work for something which doesn't have a heading under it, correct?"_ I don't know exactly what you mean by that, but so far, you did not explain that was a requirement. I also do not know what you mean by "just specify" something and getting "rows it relates to".

Comment: At the moment, your xpath finds the elements between 2 headers, but in the case of the _last_ group on the page, there isn't going to a 2nd header to reference.

I wanted to be able to provide "Heading 1" to my function in code and that will make me an xpath string that would get the elements. I didn't want to have to say "between 'Heading 1' and 'Heading 2'".

Comment: @Joe _"I wanted to be able to provide "Heading 1" to my function in code and that will make me an xpath string that would get the elements. I didn't want to have to say "between 'Heading 1' and 'Heading 2'"_ Because of this line from your question: _"I want to get all td[1]s from the trs after "Heading 1" but not anything after "Heading 2" (or including "Heading 2")."_ I thought you wanted to have elements _between_ Heading 1 and Heading 2.

Comment: I do, but I also added the note _"Ideally I need to be able to do this with only "Heading 1" as the input - I want all elements under the heading I supply, but ignoring anything under a new heading."_

Comment: @Joe I did not understand that before, sorry. See my second edit, now the path expression does not depend on "Heading 2" anymore.

Answer (score -1):

You can do something like this:

```
  <tr class="heading">
    <td colspan="2"> Heading 1 </td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td class="left">L 1</td>
    <td class="right">R 1</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td class="left">L 2</td>
    <td class="right">R 2</td>
  </tr>

  <tr class="heading">
    <td colspan="2"> Heading 2</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td class="left">L 3</td>
    <td class="right">R 3</td>
  </tr>

</body>
```

then specify the colors you want in css.

Comment: Not sure if you even read the question as I have no idea what you're answering!